# How to reference a field from within an object

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to address a field of an object in javascript from within a function in another field like this:

```
var binds = {};
var name = 'hi';
binds[name] = {
  foo: [],
  bar: {
    add: function (e) { foo.push (e); }
  }
}
```

I tried `this.foo.push (e)` and binding the function with `.bind (binds[name])` and `.bind (this)` but neither of those worked, how can I reference the `foo` element from with a function in `bar`?

EDIT:

I'm trying to reference a field which is not on the same object but higher up. So this is different from the linked question.

Comment: Your `bind` approach is correct, only it suffers from the problem mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: While the questions are similar, they aren't the same one.  The other question is asking how to initialize a property based off of others.  This question is asking how to create a method that references other properties.  Very different.  Anyway, I answered it below.

Comment: There's no JSON there. That's a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toy with a module pattern to store references to higher-up properties like this:

```
var binds = {};
var name = 'hi';

binds[name] = (function() {
    var arr = [];
    return {
        foo: arr,
        bar: {
            add: function(e) {
                arr.push(e);   
            }
        }
    }
})();

binds[name].bar.add('test');
console.log(binds[name].foo); //logs ["test"]
```

Comment: I need to have the add function deeper, see my code, it's different. This is just the simplest example

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize.  I'll delete my answer for now and come back later on tonight when I have more time :)

Comment: That's kind of what I had, I was hoping there was something less ugly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is a less ugly way to do this.  There will be other ways to do it, but all of them are eye sores.  Unfortunately, there's not  a good way to tell an object literal to "go up one level".